Reference request on dynamics and hyperbolic dynamics (hyperbolicity in absence of periodic orbits)
I  would  appreciate if  you  introduce  me  a  reference (paper  or  book)  who  address the  concept  of  hyperbolic  dynamics but  with  emphasis  on  absence of  periodic  orbits.  a possible  title  something like 'hyperbolicity in  absence  of  periodic  orbits.
My  motivation was  my  following  answer  to  certain post  in MO https://mathoverflow.net/a/476303/36688

Do you have an example in mind of a hyperbolic system without periodic orbits?

@MartinM.W.  on the $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {0}$ the map $(2x,y/3)$

I'm not sure why people are downvoting this question—I think it's reasonable—but here are a couple of reasons there might not be a rich literature on this topic. One is simply that in many natural situations, especially when there's a compactness condition, hyperbolicity implies the existence of periodic points.
To be sure, one can construct hyperbolic systems with no periodic points, as in the map in the comments: $(x, y) \rightarrow (2x, y/3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash  \{0\}$. But it's not clear what the hyperbolicity condition is good for in this simple setting, and it feels a little like "cheating": this is actually a system with a fixed point, but in disguise.
For what it's worth, it is possible to do the same thing in a slightly less trivial setting. The paper "Hyperbolic Nonwandering Sets Without Dense Periodic Points" (M. Kurata, Nagoya Math. J. Vol. 74, 1979) gives an example of a system as described in the title. Looking at their example, it seems that one could remove a finite number of points and have nontrivial hyperbolic recurrence on a non-compact manifold, without any periodic points.
Overall, it seems like hyperbolicity without periodic points ends up being a fairly restrictive condition, so there aren't a lot of natural and interesting examples. That said, who knows, there may be rich structure here that's still undiscovered!

Thank  you  very much  for  your  answer

One more point is that without recurrence, there's may not be a link between metric conditions and topology. Simplest example: the map $x \rightarrow x + 1$ could be seen as uniformly expanding or uniformly contracting, given an appropriate choice of metric on $\mathbb{R}$.
